# Provide custom validation for some properties (Maps) of a bean coming from a library/jar

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

I am building a library and I have a POJO like the Example below. There are few Maps in the POJO to let the clients pass custom properties that they can use in the server side. I would like to add the validation constraints for known fields and give the ability to add validation for the fields in the Maps to the clients.

I am able to validate the POJO using hibernate bean validator. I am looking at ways to provide validation for the maps in a way that clients can override. I have been looking at Hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=7.0#chapter-bootstrapping) but its not very clear to me.

When this library is used (typically in a spring application), each deployment can send their own key value pairs for each map. I can let them register their own custom validator for each map in their application or i can drive it through some config file where they can list the list of possible keys and values for each map. The clients may know the POJO they want to use for each map, if that can lead to cleaner solution.

The map might have mostly primitive data types (like string, boolean, integer, etc). Ideally, I would like to support custom objects as well. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
class Example {
    private One one;
    private Two two;
}

class One {
    private Eleven eleven;
    private Twelve twelve;
}

private Eleven {
    private Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
}

private Twelve {
    @NotBlank(message = "id should not be blank")
    private String id;
    @Min(value = 0, message = "Count should not be less than 0")
    private int count;
    
    private Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();     
}

private Two {
    @NotBlank(message = "id should not be blank")
    private String id;
    
    @Email(message = "Email should be valid")
    private String email;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want the maps themselves validated (e.g. that they are not empty, or they do not contain more than 5 mappings)? Do you want the keys validated (e.g. every key is a valid Java identifier)? The values (e.g. they are all future dates)? A combination of the above? And what do you mean customize the validators based on configuration, e.g. do you want to read the rules from some external properties file or is a custom validation annotation enough? A concrete example of your needs would help.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I clarified the question with the information you asked for. Is it clear now ?

Comment: Hi @srini, it's much clearer now. My first attempt to approach a solution would be a custom validator ([plenty of resources](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=canonical&q=custom+java+beans+validator&ia=web) out there). The logic of this validator would be configurable according to the client - plenty of options here too, reading a static configuration properties file (the simplest) would be my first. If you could provide a concrete, simplified example of the actual use case, someone could come up with a more specific solution.